# Prescribe zeros of a meromorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\{z_j\}_{j \geq 1}$ and $\{p_j\}_{j \geq 1}$ be sequences of distinct complex numbers.
Set
$$M(z)=1+\sum_{j=1}^{+\infty} \frac{r_j}{z-p_j}, \quad z \in \mathbb{C}.$$
Under which conditions we can find $\{r_j\}_{j \geq 1} \subset \mathbb{C}$ such that $M$ is meromorphic and
$$M(z_k)=0, \quad \forall k \geq 1.$$ ?
I guess it is linked to the Mittag-Leffler theorem but I don't see how to use it, nor if it gives sharp conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The Mittag-Leffler theorem says that there exists a meromorphic function with principal part $r_j/(z-p_j)$ at $p_j$; it does *not* say that the funtion is given by that sum. (And in fact the conclusion of ML still holds when that sum does not converge.)

It's clear that for any sequence $p_j$ there exists a sequence $r_j>0$ such that the sum converges to a meromorphic function.

Comment: I don't see why it is meaningless ? I have a function given in this form ($p_j$ fixed, $r_j$ to be chosen) and I would like to know if I can prescribe arbitrary zeros of this function by adjusting the $r_j$'s. If not, what are the conditions on $z_j$.

Comment: You'd like to know if  you can prescribe arbitrary zeroes, fine. That's not what you asked.

Comment: How do you suggest that I rewrite my question then ? For me it was clear as I wrote "Let $z_j$ and $p_j$..." (so they are fixed) and then "we can find $r_j$...?"

Comment: Sorry. I missed the first sentence - yes, it is perfectly clear.

Comment: No problem. Do you have any hint then ? I thought it was linked to the Mittag-Leffler expansion, as in this post:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/784659/series-representation-of-a-meromorphic-function-with-simple-poles?noredirect=1&lq=1